# Search multiple strings within a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I search through a string for a particular substring and find the positions of each matching item.

For example,

```
NSString *theText = @"name - dave, age - 30, favNum - 7, name - peter, age - 8, favNum - 10";
```

In this example, I am trying to find all the ages and replace them with 50. What is the best way of doing so?

Comment: Why are you holding this as a string? Can't you convert them to a dictionary?

Comment: Isn't that what he's asking :-)

Comment: Hi, that was just an example. In the code i have i pull data from a rss feed so i have a string of HTML which is then displayed back in a UIWebView. The thing is some of the images in the HTML need to be resized so i am trying to find the image height and width in the HTML string and resize them.

Comment: iPhone or Mac? Adding that tag would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSRegularExpression` is available only since iOS 4.0 and the string should have predictable regex for this to work as one would guess.

```
NSString *theText = @"name - dave, age - 30, favNum - 7, name - peter, age - 8, favNum - 10";
NSRegularExpression * regularExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<= age - )\\d+"
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                      error:nil];
    
NSString * alteredText = [regularExpression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:theText
                                                                     options:0
                                                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [theText length])
                                                                withTemplate:@"50"];

NSLog(@"%@", alteredText);
```

The above code works. You will have to see if it fits your HTML use case.

#### Getting the ages

You will use the `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:` method to enumerate through all the matches. You will get a [`NSTextCheckingResult`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTextCheckingResult) object for each iteration which will hold the range information about the match. So you will need to do this before you replace the string. You can get the ages in an array doing,

```
NSMutableArray * ages = [NSMutableArray array];
[regularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:theText
                                    options:0
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [theText length])
                                 usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
                                     [ages addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[theText substringWithRange:result.range] intValue]]];
                                 }];

NSLog(@"%@", ages);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very useful

Also is there a way to store the original value that i am changing?

Comment: like store all the values of age into an array.

Comment: You can look at `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:` method of `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: Added an example. You will get an array of `NSNumber`s.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I figured out the enumarateMatchesInString after a bit of head scratching.

Comment: one thing though, just so i understand. In NSRegularExpression what does the following mean...

(?<= age - )\\d+

Comment: `\\d+` is a regex for identifying a number. The `(?<= age - )` indicates that the number should be preceded (look behind) by ` age - ` which is what we want. You should look at the `NSRegularExpression`'s documentation. It has a lot more tools you can think of using.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to disassemble the string and then rebuild it. It is not possible to replace characters in an NSString.

First you need to split the string into components. Use NSString's `-(NSArray*)componentsSeperatedByString(@"age")`  or maybe `-(NSArray*)componentsSeperatedByString(@",")` to plit out your records. But then getting the digits needs more work. Use NSScanner.

You create an NSScanner with the string you want to scan: `+ (id)scannerWithString:(NSString *)aString`. So you would loop through the array returned above and scan a string then an integer.

To can over the strings, you need to use - (BOOL)scanCharactersFromSet:(NSCharacterSet *)scanSet intoString:(NSString **)stringValue
 using the character set: [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] inverseCharacterSet] - this is the charachter set including all characters other than the digits. Note that scanCharacters from range gives you back the characters it scans and so you can use this to rebuild the string.

Then you could scan a integer using NSScanner's `- (BOOL)scanInt:(int *)intValue`

You could probably achieve something similar using NSPredicate and regexps - there would be less code but it would be less readable.